# Ubuntu: I cannot reach internet

Tags: ubuntu, networking, network-interface

I'm trying to install nodejs on my Ubuntu server but it seems not to be able to reach the internet.

My server has two network interfaces:

1. `eth0` connected to my network
2. `eth1` used sometimes to be connected to a second network and usually not used.

My network gateway is 192.168.0.1 on a common class C network.

When I try to ping any host inside my network, everything goes fine but when I try to ping the gateway, I can't receive any response and the same happens when I try to ping any external domain, regardless of the correct name resolution provided by my DNS.

Here is my configuration:

ifconfig:

```
root:~# ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a4:5d:36:c3:44:18
          inet addr:192.168.0.168  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a65d:36ff:fec3:4418/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:31531 errors:0 dropped:108 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6734 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3896820 (3.8 MB)  TX bytes:930411 (930.4 KB)
          Interrupt:16

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a4:5d:36:c3:44:19
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:68235 (68.2 KB)  TX bytes:68235 (68.2 KB)
```

my routes:

```
root@:~# ip route show
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.168
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
        iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
        iface eth0 inet static
        metric 0
        address 192.168.0.168
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.0.0
        broadcast 192.168.0.255
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        dns-nameservers 192.168.0.3 192.168.0.2

auto eth1
        iface eth1 inet static
        metric 1
        address 192.168.1.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.168
        dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 192.168.0.168
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: So, you can ping, say, 192.168.0.77 (assume this IP address exists and live) but when you ping 192.168.0.1, it is not successful. Is that right ? If yes, what message are you getting on the terminal ? Did your machine connect to the internet before you installed the nodejs ?

Comment: Yes, it is!
Here is the terminal output

`root@:~# ping 192.168.0.1  
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.  
^C  
--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---  
11 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time  
10079ms`

Comment: please update your original post with the ping out put first. Also add output from `traceroute 192.168.0.1` command

Comment: another command `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6` ? what does it say ? `1` or `0` ?

Comment: Sorry, it seems I'm not allowed to edit my own posts...

I haven't traceroute, only traceroute6 but I'm not able to use it

Comment: Hi Mel, the output is 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37714/discussion-between-luca3003-and-melburslan).

Comment: Just an update: I connected the server directly to the router assigning a public ip to the eth0 and it works perfectly.
I think that the problem is on the network or on the firewall...

Comment: good thing you figured it out. Those intermittent failures are indicative of something wrong going on with the network. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add these lines to the bottom:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

then run command

```
sysctl -p
```

use `sudo` if you are not logged in as root. Then you should see this on the terminal:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

and

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

should give output of

```
1
```

Then try pinging the `192.168.0.1` IP address again again.

**EDIT**

Seems like commenting out the IPV6 entries in `/etc/hosts` file were also needed. Figured out after a chat session.

Comment: this is the output:

sysctl -p

`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1`

Cat's output now is 1

The ping is still without any response

Comment: Mel, why do you think it happens only with the gateway?
It answer without any problem to ping from my windows pc.
Have I to monitor some settings on the gateway?

Comment: go to the [CHAT WINDOW](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37714/discussion-between-luca3003-and-melburslan) please

Comment: As suggested by MelBurslan,
I:  
  - deleted the route to the eth1
  - disabled the ipv6 into the /etc/sysctl.conf  
  - deleted the ipv6 lines into the /etc/hosts  
  - restarted the networking service (service networking restart)  
  
  This worked for me!
Thank you very much, Mel!

Comment: Sorry to say that today the issue is back :(
Despite of the `ip route del 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1` the route is up again but when I remove it, nothing change.

IPv6 has been disabled according to what suggested by MelBurslan but even so the gateway is unreachable.

any idea?

Comment: did you reboot the machine between yesterday and today ?

Comment: Yes, I did it several times

Comment: I've seen that the deleted routes reappear after a while (I don't know why) but even deleting them again the issue remains. ipv6 has been definitely disabled.

I've also seen that there was a duplicated hostname (but not ip) issue...

Comment: The things we tried and deleted yesterday, i.e. the static routes, were done dynamically and they might be back. what does `netstat -rn` show now ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37767/discussion-between-luca3003-and-melburslan).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two default gateways. Remove the gateway command under auto eth1.

If you can't ping your gateway and it is connected to the same switch (or is the switch) you have problem not associated with gateways. Can other machines talk to the gateway, or is it the problem?

Comment out eth1's setup to avoid issues until fixed.

Comment: I commented the line and restart the network service but without any change...

Comment: Try rebooting. Try traceroute to see what is going wrong.

Comment: I also rebooted the server :(
I haven't traceroute, only traceroute6 but I don't understand how to use it

Comment: those in the output of `ip route show` command are not default gateways. They are just static routes and and they are okay as is.